# Some questions about local rings and chain rings.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

(All my rings are commutative with $1$.)

The notion of a field spews forth many derived concepts. For example:

1. An *integral domain* is a ring that can be homomorphically injected into a field.
2. A *semiprimitive ring* is a ring that can be expressed as a subdirect product of fields.
3. A *reduced ring* is a ring that can be homomorphically injected into a direct product of fields.

Now we can define that a *field* is a ring $R$ whose poset of ideals is isomorphic to the poset $\mathbb{B} = \{0 \leq 1\}.$ It seems reasonable, therefore, to try replacing this condition with some weaker condition $P$ on the ideals. The original question went on to suggest that $P$="every ideal is principal" was a reasonable starting point. I've since changed my mind. Some alternative suggestions for $P$

- $P$ = "there is a unique maximal ideal." In other words, replace fields with local rings.
- $P$ = "ideals form a chain." In other words, replace fields with chain rings.

> **Questions.**
>
> 1. Which rings can be homomorphically injected into a local ring/chain ring?
> 2. Which rings can be expressed as a subdirect product of local rings/chain rings?
> 3. Which rings can be homomorphically injected into a direct product of local rings/chain rings?

Even if these particular questions turn out to be too hard to answer, I'd nonetheless appreciate a thoughtful discussion of interesting properties and conditions that arise in this way.

Comment: I am not sure these kind of questions are interesting. For example, any domain which is a finitely generated algebra over a field (say)  can be embedded in a field (as you said) but can also be embedded in a discrete valuation ring, unless it is already a field (with the same field of fractions).

Comment: I think the questions are interesting, but are probably also hard to resolve because subrings of PIRs are probably not very nice.

Comment: I don't really get what is the question. Are you asking for a characterisation of these ring-theoretical notions in terms of their poset of ideals? I think these notions can be translated in terms of properties of the annihilators of the simple modules of the ring but, at the same time, I think they are nice enough so to expect an even better characterisation. Maybe the question is which ring-theoretic properties can be translated into an embedding property? As happens with domains, semiprimitive, reduced, and so on